# Row Number In datagrid Control WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

How can I display row number in the first cell of the datagrid control, I don't have the row number or any other information, just data from the data base and

Some Value
Some Other value

and I want the output like

First   Some Value
Secont Some Other Value

How can I do that, any idea

Answer (score -1):

The "easiest" method is to wrap your data model in a view model thank has a extra property called rowNr...

If this is not possible, also look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/05/28/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-alternating-rows.aspx